# PHP 7.2.17 removes custom session folder

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, joomla, amazon-elb

This is a bit of a multi part question. First part it a problem with PHP 7.2.17 on CentOS 7.6.1810 with Apache 2.4.6. I'm running the latest Joomla 3.9.x. When I turn on PHP session handling instead of database it works fine with the default session folder. If I set a custom folder the entire ./session folder is removed, I'm guessing on a cron or other job. Can someone point me in the right direct to get that figured out?

```
php_value session.save_path /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/session/
```

The reason for the custom session folder is the need for load balancing. I use AWS for hosting and setup an ELB with multiple ec2 instances. The event site gets a ton of traffic over a 5 day period, then falls back off so I can put it back on my shared hosting instance. I'm concerned that if a user hits one server, Joomla creates a session, then they happen to bounce to another instance they will lose their session since it wasn't with that instance.

Comment: Since no one has chimed in here, you might like to try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Its a PHP issue, not a Joomla one...